# Remove tile, or not when changing from range vent to a microhood?

Tags: ceramic-tile, microhood

I have a tiled wall behind my electric range. Ceramic tile extends up to, but not behind, the existing Whirlpool non-vented range hood. I want to remove the range hood and replace it with a microhood. I don't intend to get into a major tile project--just upgrade to the microhood.

I know that it would be easier and quicker to install the mounting bracket by bolting through the existing tile, but it would leave the microhood sticking out by the thickness of the tile (just a thin, garden variety wall tile).

The alternative would be to remove the tiles where the back of the microhood will be so that the microhood would sit flush against the drywall. It would be a lot of work, with the possibility of tile damage.

Right now, I am inclined to just mount the microhood with the existing tile in place.

I would appreciate any comments regarding the pros and cons of either plan, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leaving the tile in place (if it is aesthetically acceptable) in case you (or a future owner) ever want to change back to a traditional vent hood; the micros do not last forever either, a future change of style or brand will likely be a different size.